# need to generate text box automatically when I click on the mouse point in image box (while after browsing image in the form.) for the .net form

Tags: c#

I need generate text box while I click on the mouse point in image box. in this code only generate text box click on the form. it not generate text box for click on the image box.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        tb.Width = 100;
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> public Form1()
>   { 
>      InitializeComponent();
>      this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
>   }

This code of yours adds the mousedown event on the form .
If you want to have the mouse down event in the image box ,
Do this

1) Go to form designer
2) In the properties of image box, go to events and in mousedown choose the Form1_MouseDown event.

Hope this helps